# How to get the index of current item in swiper slider?

Tags: angular, swiper.js

In angular i am using swiper slider, I want to catch my current active slider index. How can I do it?
html

```
<swiper-container #swiper slides-per-view="1" pagination="true" pagination- 
clickable="true"
(slidechange)="slideChange($event)">
<swiper-slide *ngFor="let i of images"><img mat-card-image [src]="i" alt="Image">
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('swipper') private swipperREF: any;
images:any=['assets/images/image_1.png','assets/images/image_1.png','assets/images/image_1.png']

onSlideChange() {
console.log(this.swipperREF.swiperRef.activeIndex);
}
```

how to get the current active index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiper events should be added like `swiperslidechange` for slide change!

#### [Swiper Event Docs](https://swiperjs.com/element#events)

> All Swiper events are available as native DOM events but with lowercase names and swiper prefix (configurable via events-prefix parameter). E.g. slideChange becomes swiperslidechange.

So you can access the current Index by giving `const activeIndex = e?.detail?.[0]?.activeIndex;`

Working example!

html

```
<swiper-container
  #swiper
  slides-per-view="1"
  pagination="true"
  pagination-clickable="true"
  (swiperslidechange)="onSlideChange($event)"
>
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let i of images"
    ><img mat-card-image [src]="i" alt="Image" />
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
})
export class SwiperComponent {
  images: any = [
    'https://placehold.co/600x400',
    'https://placehold.co/600x400',
    'https://placehold.co/600x400',
  ];

  onSlideChange(e: any) {
    const activeIndex = e?.detail?.[0]?.activeIndex;
    console.log(activeIndex);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-spbwmh?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html,src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.ts)